How can I optimize the execution time of a Map/Reduce script in NetSuite?
I’m working on a NetSuite Map/Reduce script to process large volumes of invoice data for XML generation. However, I’m facing performance issues and delays during execution.
The script takes approximately 2-3 minutes to complete, which is unacceptable for user experience as I need the XML file to be generated immediately upon clicking a custom button on invoice record.
I will appreciate the alternative solution!

Please could you show some of your code? I'd suggest perhaps getting the values using SuiteQL, if you're loading and doing get value etc

There is no way to guarantee map/reduce script completion times.
When triggered they are put in a queue. Their start time depends on number of factors like how many SuiteCloud Processors you have configured in your account and what other jobs are using those processors.
One option that I've used is calculate the governance of the file generation task. If you can do that then you could library-ize your code and generate your files immediatedly in a suitescript if the job is small enough or generate them and email the result from a map/reduce if the job is larger.
